# How do I publish on Azure a WebRTC application using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webrtc, azure-web-app-service

I'm using this example to start learning about WebRTC: https://github.com/gongfuPanada/dot-net-webrtc

I'm used to MVC, so I thought it would be easier to understand.

After making the changes I wanted, I published it on azure web site, but it doesn't work.

This is the index page on the sample:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Peer.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/StreamManager.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/WsSignalChannel.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/WebRtc.js")"></script>
        <style>

            body {
                font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px; 
            }

            .videoWrapper {
                border: solid 1px #CCC;
                box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
                float: left;
                padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
                width: 600px;
                margin: 5px;
            }

            video {
                width: 600px;
                height: 400px;
                margin-top: 5px;
            }
        </style>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>WebRTC</title>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="getUserMediaFail" style="display:none;">
        No signal from WebCam 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I debug the application on VS everything works fine, but when it is published it shows only "getUserMediaFail".

What am I missing?

Comment: According to the [documentations](https://developers.voxbone.com/docs/webrtc/overview/), this error indicates that the browser doesn't have access to your mic. Can it be that the Azure website automatically blocks the access to your mic?

Comment: @Gunnar I don't know, can you teel me how to check? thank you

Comment: Go [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?hl=en) and open the "Change camera and mic permissions" sub-menu for directions for settings in Chrome. Unless you are using other browser, then you just need to find similar settings.

Comment: @Gunnar I've already tried it, but it's not that the problem. I suspect it may be they way I have to publush the stun server inside the solution..

Comment: Could be. I'm not familiar with WebRTC, so I can't say. I just thought it was browser related.

Comment: @Gunnar Thanks anyway, if you have more experience with azure, please let me know, thank you again!